# How to write gcast for type families?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm trying to write a variant of `Data.Typeable.gcast` which works for type families of kind `* -> *`.  What I'm looking for is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Typeable

type family T

gcastT :: (Typeable a,Typeable b) => T a -> Maybe (T b)
gcastT = undefined -- but that's not working too well!
```

going by analogy to `gcast :: (Typeable a,Typeable b) => f a -> Maybe (f b)`.

Is this possible?

I *could* change the context to `(Typeable (T a),Typeable (T b)) =>` but I'd prefer this signature for aesthetic reasons: `gcast` doesn't need `Typeable1 f`, after all.

---

Some background in case I'm solving the wrong problem for what I actually want to achieve: my goal is to write a function `matchAndExtract`:

```
matchAndExtract :: (Eq a, Typeable a, Eq b, Typeable b) => a -> b -> T b -> Maybe (T a)
matchAndExtract x k v = if (cast x == Just k) then gcastT v else Nothing
```

which checks `x` and `k` for being of the same type and being equal, and then returning the supplied `T b` (which we by then know to be the same as `T a` - T might not be injective, but it *is* a function!) or `Nothing`, otherwise.

I've got a work-around by wrapping the offending `T a` in a `newtype`, using `gcast`, and unwrapping again:

```
matchAndExtractF :: (Eq a, Typeable a, Eq b, Typeable b) => a -> b -> f b -> Maybe (f a)
matchAndExtractF x k v = if (cast x == Just k) then gcast v else Nothing

newtype WrapT a = WrapT { unWrapT :: T a }

matchAndExtractViaWrap :: (Eq a, Typeable a, Eq b, Typeable b) => a -> b -> T b -> Maybe (T a)
matchAndExtractViaWrap x k v = fmap unWrapT $ matchAndExtractF a k (WrapT v)
```

but that just rubs me the wrong way! This also works for instances for which `T a` is not an instance of `Typeable`; that again seems to me to indicate the `Typeable (T a)` contexts shouldn't be needed.

The work-around is perfectly acceptable, but I'd like to get rid of the spurious `WrapT` type.

Comment: not possible.   Type families are not injective, and as such you can't solve the constraint from which them come in this way.

Comment: But knowing `Typeable a` doesn't imply `Typeable (T a)`!

Comment: @DanielWagner: True, but my limited tests included a case where `T a` was explicitly not a member of `Typeable`. Now I don't understand why `matchAndExtractViaWrap` works! Could that be a bug in GHC (I'm using 7.6.1)? I'll try to implement `unsafeCoerce` tomorrow...

Comment: @yatima2975 Type families + newtypes are known to be unsound, yep. See also [Trac #1496](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1496).

Comment: @DanielWagner: Well, it also works when I use `data WrapT = ...` but I fortunately haven't been able to write anything 'bad'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible they way you have implemented it.  Instead you can use

```
type family T x :: *
newtype NT x = NT {fromNT :: T x}
gcastT :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => NT a -> Maybe (NT b)
gcastT = gcast
```

In this case you do not need to use the `Eq` constraint.

Another option is to reify the typeable dictionaries into GADTs

```
data Type x where
  Typeable :: Typeable x => Type x

asT :: NT x -> Type x -> NT x
asT = const

gcastTD :: Type a -> Type b -> Type a -> Maybe (T b)
gcastTD t@Typeable Typeable x = fmap fromNT $ gcastT $ (NT x) `asT` t
```

(code not tested, but should be almost correct)

once you have this you can use it by passing explicit type signatures

```
type instance T Int = ()

justUnit = gcastTD (Typeable :: Type Int) (Typeable :: Type Int) ()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I went with.